# Visual studio change IDE color based on build configuration

Tags: visual-studio, ide

I would like to know if it's possible to change header background color or any background color of the Visual studio IDE based on the build configuration choosen. For example, the entire toolbar is green when build configuration is Debug and Red when Release.

We are using Visual Studio 2017 Professional.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?  I am looking for the same thing.

Comment: Unfortunately no :(